# Cannot create a custom view using Xib file due to nil subviews

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

I have a XIB file with 5 subviews. The XIB is set to a custom class like so

```
class Slide: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var loLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var humidityLabel: UILabel!

}
```

I instantiate like so `let slide = Slide()`

When I try to set the variables ie `slide.descriptionLabel = "Hello"`

I get error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The stack trace shows that the XIB is instantiated, but the subviews are nil, and, therefore, cannot be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have to load the nib file ( here i suppose nib name is **Slide** )

```
let slide  = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! Slide
```

as this

```
let slide = Slide()
```

loads the view without it's layout so all attached views are `nil`

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with custom views, using Xibs, you should load them first.

So, for example, in your `Slide` class you can create a static function like:

```
static func createView(with owner: Any) -> Slide {
    let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "YourNibName", bundle: nil)
    let views = nib.instantiate(withOwner: owner, options: nil)
    let view = views[0] as! Slide
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}
```

where `YourNibName` should be the name of your Xib file.

This static function can be used like:

```
let slide = Slide.createView(with: self)

// attach the view to a superview
aSuperview.addSubview(slide)

// setup the right constraints
// for example
slide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aSuperview.topAnchor).isActive = true
// ...and so on
```

The important bit is then to set in Interface Builder the right view for your Xib:

[image]

To recap your view should look like (note that I renamed `Slide` to `SlideView`. It sounds better to me):

```
class SlideView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var descriptionImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var hiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var loLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var humidityLabel: UILabel!

    static func createView(with owner: Any) -> SlideView {
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "YourNibName", bundle: nil)
        let views = nib.instantiate(withOwner: owner, options: nil)
        let view = views[0] as! SlideView
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }
}
```